# hello world script causes memory leak

Tags: python, scripting, memory-management

My script generates about 400 objects. If I run the same script twice, I notice the object count remains the same, but the memory allocated does increase substantially.

I thought it was my code (and it may still be), but can someone explain why the following piece of code causes a small (but noticeable) memory leak?

This is after I hold both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (which runs the script) and I keep my eye on |Mem:11.12M| on top of the blender UI. It increases by .01M every ~5 seconds.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('hello')
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not cause any memory leak. It simply adds entries into your *Undo* list, and depending on how many undo steps you have setup in preferences the Mem reading will cap out eventually and will not grow any further.

Comment: Why would 'print' add items to the undo list?

Comment: Ran my actual code instead. Each time I execute it, memory keeps increasing. (while # of Objects stays the same). This is after I modified the "Undo" preferences by setting "Steps" to 2 and "Memory Limit" to 1.

Comment: @user1798810 running the *RunScript* operator adds this action into the undo list, so everything the script does can be undone. You can check the Undo list by pressing Ctrl-Alt-Z inside 3d view window. It is possible your full script experiences memory leaks, but I don't see this with `print("Hello")`